# As I can do Bootstrap alert, pressing a button to change language

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, alerts

I have a problem, which I try to do an alert when the visitor changes the language of the web, the alert is create but disappear, because that is changing the link by:

```
?locale=es || ?locale=en || http://localhost:3000/pages/index?locale=en
```

The default is in English, but the push the button, the alert your duration is for 0.5 seconds and disappear.

As I can make the alert remains until you delete it?

Note: Im use Ruby On Rails.

My Button:

```
    <li><a href="?locale=en" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" id="AlertEN"> <%= t('menuLen')%></a></li>
```

Code My Alert:

```
<div class="container">    
        <center>
            <div class="alert alert-success" id="successChangeEN" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your Language is now English.

            </div>
        </center>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
    <script>
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
            $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>')

        }

$('#AlertEN').on('click', function() {
            bootstrap_alert.warning('You change the language success!');
});
</script>
```

I hope to answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example using cookies http://jsfiddle.net/0Lcofr6x/show/

Source Code Here: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lcofr6x/

Url is not changing due the fact fiddle does not accept dummy query string but trust me you are navigating to same page (reload).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#AlertEN').attr('href', window.location.href);    
    bootstrap_alert = function() {}
    bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
        $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>');
        $('#alert_placeholder .close').unbind( "click" );
        $('#alert_placeholder .close').on('click', function() { $('#alert_placeholder').hide();
                                                               $('.alert-success').show();
                                                                  });

            }

    $('#AlertEN').on('click', function() {       
                $.cookie("changed_locale", "You change the language success!"); 


    });

     $('.alert-success').hide();
    if ($.cookie("changed_locale") != null)
    {
        bootstrap_alert.warning('You change the language success!');
    }
    $.removeCookie("changed_locale");
});
```

Comment: Apparently this correct, but does not display the alert.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/b2b9ca2922379ab49f79312acabd65e8
This is screenshot for the web to press the buttom